# submitting in a form only sends some information

Tags: html, forms

I have the following setup

```
<form method="post" action="createPdf.php" autocomplete="on">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="projectName" id="text5"><br/>

        <br/>

        <input type="hidden" name="numItems" id="numItemsId">
        <input type="submit" name="Print PDF" value="Print PDF" onclick="send()">
    </p>

    <div>
    <span class="rightSide">

    <input type="text" name="rollsMatName" id="rollsMat">
    </span><br/></br>
    </div>

    <div>
    <span class="rightSide">

    <input type="text" name="rollsFFName" id="rollsFF">
    </span><br/></br>
    </div>
</form>
```

The submit button will send the info of the text fields 1 and 2 but not 3. What is going on here?

I get the following error from php:
Notice: Undefined index: rollsFFName in C:\wamp\www\Quote Template\createPdf.php on line 372

Here is a portion of my php code in createPdf.php

```
        $quantity[$counter] = $_POST["rollsMatName"];

        $quantity[$counter] = $_POST["rollsFFName"];
```

Comment: We can't tell unless we see your actual code.

Comment: Please post your real code here?

Comment: Not sure how to post it with formatting to read better

Comment: @user2382321: Please [edit] your original post, and not in a comment. We can't make anything out of this.

Comment: Why do you have `</button>` without an opening tag?

Comment: @user2382321 and what about PHP? How do you know it doesn't send data from 3? And what's that `</button>`? Makes definitely no sense!

Comment: Your html markup is completely invalid but your data still is being sent over to PHP, you are making some mistake while receiving it in php kindly post your php code.

Comment: Your HTML is perfectly invalid. What are all those `</button>`s doing there? You should validate your form HTML, that's most likely why your data isn't being properly sent.

Comment: Sorry those </button> tags were there in error. I have deleted them and updated the original post. The problem still exists

Comment: kindly post php code too

Comment: Go back to your html form in browser refresh your page enter new data then post and then check your result because your code says there shouldn't be any error for rollsMatName.

Comment: There isn't an error for rollsMatName only for rollsFFName

Comment: @user2382321 strange... PHP does throw an error because of undefined index? O_o

Comment: @user2382321 bro you are making mistake somewhere else without full code can't help because i've tested your code here and its working like a charm.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can post my full code? Ive got three separate files each of 400 lines each roughly

Comment: @user2382321 Post only interesting pieces of code. If you really want to publish all of your code, use something like pastebin.com; [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87451/long-code-snippets-that-are-relevant-to-the-question) is a meta discussion about sharing your code.

Comment: @user2382321 and **don't wory about that downvotes!** It's a bad question but that doesn't mean that you're not going to be a moderator one day :)

Answer (score 1):

On formatting note, you should remove `</button>` tags as they have not been opened/closed properly. You can read up on some [basic HTML formatting here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp). E.g most tags will either be self closing like the `<br />` tag or have a open/close partnership `<p> </p>`.

Break tags should be `<br />` not `</br>`.

A basic view of your code would look something like the below:

```
<form method="post" action="createPdf.php" autocomplete="on">

    <input type="hidden" name="numItems" id="numItemsId" />

    <input type="text" name="projectName" id="text5" />
    <input type="text" name="rollsMatName" id="rollsMat" />
    <input type="text" name="rollsFFName" id="rollsFF" />

    <input type="submit" name="Print PDF" value="Print PDF" onclick="send()" />

</form>
```

In your PHP code you should probably change the `$counter` attribute before you write the second string to `$quantity`, eg:

```
$quantity[$counter] = $_POST["rollsMatName"];
$counter++;
$quantity[$counter] = $_POST["rollsFFName"];
```

Comment: I do that. Just edited it out when I posted it here.